# SELECT query not returning in desired order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have the SELECTed query return in order by Number. This is currently what is being returned:

[image]

And here is the current query:

```
SELECT 
    [Number] + ' - ' + SUBSTRING([Title], 1, 40) AS [StoryName]
    ,[PK_Story]
FROM Story STY
INNER JOIN Task TSK ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
INNER JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
WHERE ProductId = @productIdParam
    AND DTH.ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam
        AND @endDateParam
GROUP BY [Number]
    ,[Number] + ' - ' + SUBSTRING([Title], 1, 40)
    ,[PK_Story]
HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY [Number] ASC
```

I am attempting to order by `[Number]` which is the CMIS-##. As you can see I have the `ORDER BY` attempting to do this but the resulting order is incorrect. The lower values 'CMIS-43' is not at the top. How do I fix this?

Edit:

This was ultimately my solution to deal with variable length of `[Number]`:

```
SELECT [Number] + ' - ' + SUBSTRING([Title], 1, 40) AS [StoryName]
        ,[PK_Story]
FROM Story STY
INNER JOIN Task TSK ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
INNER JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
WHERE ProductId = @productParam
      AND DTH.ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam
            AND @endDateParam
GROUP BY [Number]
     ,[Number] + ' - ' + SUBSTRING([Title], 1, 40)
     ,[PK_Story]
HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING([Number], CHARINDEX('-',[Number]) + 1, LEN([Number])) AS INT)
```

Comment: number is not a numeric value is a string, the order returned is ok as long as is treated as a string. In a string any number starting by 3 will come up before any number starting by a 4, no matter if its a 3000 or a 43.

Comment: `ORDER BY Convert(BigInt,[Number]) ASC` ... might want to add an ISNUMERIC to it and set them to some default value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING([Number], 6, LEN([number])-5) AS INT)
```

Comment: While I upvoted it, this will only work if the number of non-numeric characters before the first number is always 5.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your list is being sorted as a string, and you want it sorted numerically.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT [Number] + ' - ' + SUBSTRING([Title], 1, 40) AS [StoryName]
    ,[PK_Story], CAST(SUBSTRING([Number], 5, 3) AS int) AS [CMNumber]
FROM Story STY
INNER JOIN Task TSK ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
INNER JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON DTH.TaskId = TSK.PK_Task
WHERE ProductId = @productIdParam
    AND DTH.ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam
        AND @endDateParam
GROUP BY [Number]
    ,[Number] + ' - ' + SUBSTRING([Title], 1, 40)
    ,[PK_Story]
HAVING SUM(DTH.[Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY CMNumber ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

[Number] is a string/varchar, so the ordering is lexicographic (alphabetical) rather than numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is that you are trying to do numeric sorts on text.  In other words, while the number 10 is greater than the number 9, the string '9' is greater than the string '10'.

To solve it, you will have to another field to your select and group by clauses.  This field will use string functions to get the numeric part of the number field, and then cast it to an integer.  I'll leave the details to you.